# How to redirect index.php in subdomain to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Right now I redirect si.pokercash4free.com  to www.si.pokercash4free.com

How can I redirect si.pokercash4free.com/index.php to www.si.pokercash4free.com

Right now this is the code

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^si.pokercash4free.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.si.pokercash4free.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance,
M.

Comment: Why dont you do it with a php Header() function? something like this:   Header("Location: www.si.pokercash4free.com");

Comment: Why would you do it with a php Header() function? @Sirotoshipizdetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule **before your existing rules**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^si\.pokercash4free\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

**UPDATE:** As per comments

Have this additional rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/bbb/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Works...Thanks...

I have one more question...how can I redirect for example www.example.com/aaa/bbb/test.php  to www.example.com/aaa/test.php ?

I just want to remove that "bbb" from url. I have standard redirection non-www to www and index.php to root

Comment: OK sure I will suggest you a solution for that once I come back to my computer.